# Choosing the parameter in a function to bring the function as close to 1 as possible when x is approximately equal to zero.

Tags: calculus, approximation, linear-approximation

The problem states the following:

How should the parameter **λ** be chosen so that f(x) = e^(-λx)/(1+2sin(x)) remains as close to 1 as possible, when x ≈ 0?

I understand that the solution first simplifies the function into a simpler approximation. However, the last line in the solution states the following: So F is const. to 1st order if λ = -2. I dont quite understand what is meant with this statement.

[Problem with Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nMQu.png)

Comment: MathSE reviewers are going to wonder why I answered a question that had defects, with respect to [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  It is because you presented the question very clearly, and demonstrated that you had made an effort to understand the work, and then presented a very specific question.  Your question focused on the Math author's confusing choice of language.  I feel that your question deserves an answer.

Comment: On the other hand, please remove all of the embedded links in your posting and replace them with Math expressed with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that $\lambda$ is chosen so that $(1 - \lambda x) (1 - 2x)$ will equal $1 + (0 \times x) + (\text{something}~ \times x^2).$